# Glitchy javascript persistent header implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code: http://jsfiddle.net/KCb5z/7/

It is designed to allow me to click links on the yellow bar and also have it be pesistent. It seems to work for the most part but on transition scrolling down it glitches around the part where the yellow bar becomes persistent at the top of the page.

I believe it is this bit of code which is causing it:

```
var $select = $('#select');
var $window = $(window);
var isFixed = false;
var init = $select.length ? $select.offset().top : 0;

$window.scroll(function () {
    var currentScrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
    if (currentScrollTop > init && isFixed === false) {
        isFixed = true;
        $select.css({
            top: 0,
            position: 'fixed'
        });
    } else if (currentScrollTop <= init && isFixed === true) {
        isFixed = false;
        $select.css('position', 'relative');
    }
});
```

Is it obvious what is causing the issue, because if you scroll all the way down to the bottom it works fine.

Comment: What browser? Looks fine for me on Chrome 34. Also, you might want to update `scrollTop` on nav click to `scrollTop: $(divId).offset().top - $select.height()` to make sure you offset the height of the navbar and the user can see the *top* of the section

Comment: I'm using Chrome too. It's shown by either dragging the right slider bar up and down, or instead if you click several times on "posting" on the yellow bar it goes a bit haywire. Using the mouse wheel seems to hide the glitch

Comment: @RGraham If I do as you suggest I get a brown gap at the top of the yellow bar when I click on "posting": http://jsfiddle.net/2vY6G/  Do you know how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The glitching seems to be caused by the document re-flowing when the select element changes state from `relative` to `static`, and vice versa.  You need to find a way to stop the re-flow, either by leaving a placeholder element to occupy the space left when the element is removed from the flow (a duplicate element with `visibility:hidden` perhaps), or by making sure it doesn't affect the document flow in the first place.